# Keeping the numbers in fraction only while Matrix Multiplication in a scientific calculator

Tags: matrices, calculator

While performing a matrix multiplication on my scientific calculator (*CASIO fx-991ES PLUS*), I realized that the calculator gives out the answers in decimals (approx. decimals in case of irrational answers) even if I enter the numbers in fractional forms myself. Is there some way in which I can command my calculator to stop doing this?

For e.g., let's say some of my entries in the matrices to be multiplied are irrational numbers like $\sqrt{2}$, then as soon as I enter it, the calculator approximates it to *1.414213562* and then in the final product matrix all entries are turned into decimals from where I can't exactly find what the entry really is, say if some entry in final product matrix is *0.2828427125*, then its hard to conclude that in irrational fractional form, the number actually approximates $\sqrt{2}/5$.

I need the latter because sometimes situations demand the same.

Though it seems that I'm expecting too much from life but still, is there some way I can make the calculator stop converting the input entries into decimals in the very first place ( because getting an irrational number from a non-terminating decimal is obviously not possible, so what if the calculator computes everything i.e., numerator and denominator separately and never perform the division operation throughout the process )

*Just in case this isn't the right stack site, please suggest me as I couldn't find any better*

Comment: +1 for a well-worded question.

Comment: https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee What is this website actually, kindly give some context.

Comment: PARI/GP computer algebra system. you can use it online as well.